# Golang inject package fields by google wire

Tags: go

Can I inject package fields by google wire, now I need a struct and inject the value of struct :

```
package ABC

func NewA(inb *inb) A{
    return A{
        b: inb ,
    }
}

type Astruct {
    b *B
}
```

Now I what the value direct in package , not via a struct

```
package ABC

var b *B
var c *C
```

How to inject it by google wire, I think set it by ABC.b= in a constructor function is not a good idea because I receive b via injection
Thank you